# Default font in Nimbus

Tags: java, cross-platform, nimbus

I'm making a program that should be as platform independent as possible. I'm using the Nimbus LAF.

I was wondering, should I be worried about fonts? Is it's default font included in the LAF itself or does it fetch it from the platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a default non-system font.

If you have a frame, and you add this line after `frame.setVisible(true)`:

```
System.out.println("Font: "+frame.getFont().getName());
```

It should print `Font: Dialog` which is not a system font. So it should be a proprietary cross-platform font.

So, to answer your question:

> Should I be worried about fonts?

No, unless:

1. You use the system look and feel, which uses the system default font
2. You use another look and feel which uses the system default font
3. You use a custom font (a custom *system* font, because if you load a font you saved in the application resources it won't be a problem)

If you are doing none of the three listed above, you should be safe.